# Show multiple loading indicators for clicked elements

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let notificacao of notificacoes; let i = index">
   {{notificacao.marketplace}}
   {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} 
   {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'shortTime'}}
   <h6><strong>{{notificacao.mensagem}}</strong>
      <i *ngIf="loading && identificadorLoading == notificacao.identificador"></i>
      <svg *ngIf="identificadorLoading !== notificacao.identificador || !loading" (click)="testaLoadingExclusao(notificacao.identificador, i)">
      </svg>
   </h6>
</div>
```

my function `testaLoadingExclusao()`

```
testaLoadingExclusao(identificador, index){
    this.loading = true;
    this.identificadorLoading = identificador
}
```

How i can make the loading show in more than 1 element clicked?

What i have now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of only keeping track of one loading indicator try using an array like so:

```
private identificadorLoading: string[] = [];

....

testaLoadingExclusao(identificador, index){
    this.loading = true;
    this.identificadorLoading.push(identificador);
}
```

and in your html:

```
<div *ngFor="let notificacao of notificacoes; let i = index">
   {{notificacao.marketplace}}
   {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} 
   {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'shortTime'}}
   <h6><strong>{{notificacao.mensagem}}</strong>
      <i *ngIf="loading && identificadorLoading.includes(notificacao.identificador)"></i>
      <svg *ngIf="!identificadorLoading.includes(notificacao.identificador) || !loading" (click)="testaLoadingExclusao(notificacao.identificador, i)">
  </svg>
   </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: I already try using includes, but i receive: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: That suggests that your variable is not properly initialized. Make sure that `identificadorLoading ` always references an array.

Comment: this works when i put an elvis operator: *ngIf="loading && identificadorLoading?.includes(notificacao.identificador)"